# Taylor expansion of the electrostatic potential $1/\|\cdot \|$

Tags: taylor-expansion, vector-analysis, potential-theory

I have stumbled over this problem several times in electrodynamics, and I just don't get the hang of it.
The task is to do a Taylor expansion of $\,f(\vec{x},\,\vec{a}) = \frac{1}{\|\,\vec{x}-\vec{a}\|}$, for $\|\,\vec{a}\| \ll \|\,\vec{x}\|$. What I do, is

$$ \frac{1}{\left\|\,\vec{x}-\vec{a}\right\|} = \frac{1}{\left\|\,\vec{x}\right\| \left\|\,\hat{x}- \frac{\left\|\,\vec{a}\right\|}{\left\|\,\vec{x}\right\|}
\hat{a}\right\|}$$

In one dimension, I could now say that one number is much smaller than the other, and hence taylor it around zero. But here we're talking vectors, and I don't see which rules apply here. I don't want to write out the norms in terms of square roots, this is really messy, but rather use some rules like $\nabla \frac{1}{\|\,\vec{x}\|} = \frac{\vec{x}}{\|\,\vec{x}\|^3}$.

Comment: TeX remark: `$\|\vec x\|$` looks better than `$||\vec x||$`, and works better with `\left`, `\right`.

Comment: Thanks, I've been struggling with formatting vectors and norms correctly for some time. Is there any way to move the hats and arrows to the 'correct' location aswell? They look slightly misplaced.

Comment: Slightly misplaced, yes: MathJax has to deal with the limitations of HTML/CSS positioning, so it's not as picture-perfect as TeX itself. I would not worry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit messy. Luckily, you are not the first person who wanted to have a Taylor series for the electrostatic/Newtonian potential. [Legendre worked this out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Applications_of_Legendre_polynomials_in_physics) in the 18th century.

> But here we're talking vectors, and I don't see which rules apply here.

Yes, it's a bit confusing. This is why one fixes the direction of $\vec a$ (really, just the angle between $\vec a$ and $\vec x$), and then works with the single-variable function whose argument is the magnitude of $\vec a$. See the article linked above.

Comment: There's quite some insight in here! Now I see how the Legendre Polynomials arise in multipole expansions and hence the eigenfunctions of the laplacian! This just made quite a bunch of connections. Very nice, thanks a lot.